# Get record of another field with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am new in MongoDB world.

I've following data in my collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5735d8d4d147aa34e440988f"), 
    "DeviceLogId" : "26962", 
    "DeviceId" : "10", 
    "UserId" : "78", 
    "LogDateTime" : ISODate("2016-05-12T07:52:44.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5735d8d4d147aa34e4409890"), 
    "DeviceLogId" : "26963", 
    "DeviceId" : "10", 
    "UserId" : "342", 
    "LogDateTime" : ISODate("2016-05-12T07:54:09.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5735d8d4d147aa34e4409891"), 
    "DeviceLogId" : "26964", 
    "DeviceId" : "10", 
    "UserId" : "342", 
    "LogDateTime" : ISODate("2016-05-12T07:54:10.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5735d8d4d147aa34e4409892"), 
    "DeviceLogId" : "26965", 
    "DeviceId" : "10", 
    "UserId" : "78", 
    "LogDateTime" : ISODate("2016-05-12T07:54:27.000+0000")
}
```

I want to query `DeviceId` of each user with maximum `LogDateTime` using group by.

I've written group by query like below but have no idea how would I get `DeviceLogId` for each record.

```
collectionName.aggregate(
        [{
            $match: { LogDateTime: { $gt: todaysDateStart, $lt: todayDateEnd } }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$UserId",
                maxPunchTime: { $max: { $add: [ "$LogDateTime", 330*60000 ] } },
            }
        }])
```

In MSSQL, I could easily do it with nested query but I've no idea how would I achieve that in MongoDB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [$addToSet Group Accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/):

```
    collectionName.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: { LogDateTime: { $gt: todaysDateStart, $lt: todayDateEnd } }
    }
    , {
        $group: {
            _id: "$UserId",
            maxPunchTime: { $max: { $add: [ "$LogDateTime", 330*60000 ] } },             
            deviceLogIds:{$addToSet: "$DeviceLogId"}  //<----
        }
    } , 
    { $sort: {"maxPunchTime" : -1} } , {$limit : 1}  //Sort Descending + Limit to 1
    ])
```

Comment: I do not want set of `DeviceLogId`. I just want one `DeviceLogId` having maximum `LogDateTime`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It gives me an array of `DeviceLogIDs`. I've no idea which one to pick.

Comment: I added sort (Descending) on `$LogDateTime` very first and then it worked. And I used `$first` instead of `$addToSet` to just get one record. And it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add deviceid to an array in group phase,

```
  Device:{$addToSet:deviceId}
```